# how to put some characters between others to make price value userfriendly?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, split

I have a string like price:

```
string price= "5000000";
```

but i want to know, how can i change it (in c#) to something like this:

```
"5,000,000"
```

because it's very better and user friendly.

Comment: Why is your price stored as a `string`?

Comment: @David does that work for strings?